# How can I get the product price from WooCommerce so i can use it with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following html-block and some related Javascript code that I want to use in WooCommerce single product pages:

```js
function calcPMT(doseis,poso)
{
    var n = parseFloat(doseis);
    var i = parseFloat(0.009);
    var pv=0, sinolo=0, dosi=0, tdosi=0;
    var tposo = parseFloat(poso);
    
    pv = parseFloat(tposo);
        
      if (pv>0)
    {
        tdosi = (-1*((((i)*((pv)))/(1-Math.pow((1+(i)),(n)))-(i)*(pv))/(1+0*(i))));
        tdosi = Math.round(tdosi*100)/100;
    }

    dosi = Math.round((tdosi)*100)/100;
    sinolo = Math.round(((tdosi*doseis))*100)/100;
        
    if (doseis=="" || doseis=="0" || doseis=="1")
    {
            document.getElementById("doseis_info").innerHTML = " ";
      }
      else
      {
          document.getElementById("doseis_info").innerHTML = "€ " + dosi + " /Μήνα. Σύνολο  " + sinolo + " €";
    }
}
```

```html
<select name="doseis" onchange="calcPMT(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,Product-price);">
    <option value selected>Χωρίς Δόσεις</option>
    <option value="2">2 Δόσεις</option>
    <option value="3">3 Δόσεις</option>
    <option value="4">4 Δόσεις</option>
</select>
<span id="doseis_info"> </span>
```

But I don't know how I can get the product price and to use it on `onchange(calcPMT)` function as the second argument value, replacing in the html-code block `Product-price` by the current product price value.

How can I get the product price and to use it on `onchange(calcPMT)` function as the second argument value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the product price, for your Javascript function you will use the following:

```
<?php
global $product;

if( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_id());
}
$price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product );
?>
<select name="doseis" onchange="calcPMT(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, <?php echo $price; ?>);">
    <option value selected>Χωρίς Δόσεις</option>
    <option value="2">2 Δόσεις</option>
    <option value="3">3 Δόσεις</option>
    <option value="4">4 Δόσεις</option>
</select>
<span id="doseis_info"> </span>
```

It should work…